# Undefined index: auto-renew

Tags: civicontribute, civimember

Upon opening contribution page, we get the following PhP errors showing ABOVE the contribution pages.
See [JGSNY Contribution Page](https://jgsny.org/membership-privileges/join-civi)

**Notice: Undefined index: auto_renew in /home/jgsny/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/Form/ContributionBase.php on line 1244**

ALSO:

**Notice: Undefined index: auto_renew in /home/jgsny/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Price/BAO/PriceSet.php on line 847**

Auto-renewal options are off for all contribution pages; database tables have indexes on all relevant pages. Civicrm status shows OK.

Quick answers appreciated - this is membership renewal time and must have membership renewal form working.

Thanks,
Kate

Answer (score 1):

For a quick fix, change `$memType['auto_renew']` to `($memType['auto_renew'] ?? 0)` for the first one, and

change `$membershiptTypeValue['auto_renew']` to `!empty($membershiptTypeValue['auto_renew'])` for the second one.